# How to check return value of a function parameter before passing it to another function

Tags: c, function, return-value

```
wr_crc( rmgd.msg, sizeof( rmgd.msg ), &wr_idx, calc_crc_full( rmgd.msg, wr_idx ) );
```

Here I want to check the value of `calc_crc_full( rmgd.msg, wr_idx )` before I pass it to function

if ((wr_uint8(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, ROUTE) == SUCCESS) && 
    (wr_uint8(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, (UINT8)lib_position_reverse()) == SUCCESS) && 
    (wr_uint32(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, route_rev) == SUCCESS) &&      (wr_crc_ccitt(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, calc_crc_ccitt_full(msg, wr_idx) ) == SUCCESS))

Comment: what do you mean _check_? print? store? what?

Comment: Voting to close as too trivial / not useful to others in the future.  Am I just getting old and grumpy, or do other people think students should ask their professors such basic questions?  (assuming OP is a student, since it's just past September.)  If not a student, IDK, I thought programming textbooks / tutorials taught the super-basics like this.

Comment: It's either us or googling or asking OPs professors/teachers?

Answer (score 4):

So use an intermediate variable:

```
whatever_crc_full_is_t crcVal = calc_crc_full( rmgd.msg, wr_idx );
if( crcVal != 0 ) {
    wr_crc( rmgd.msg, sizeof( rmgd.msg ), &wr_idx, crcVal ); 
}
```

Comment: @Chauchan The if clause you posted does not have function call calc_crc_full() in it. It is not clear what value you want to check.

Comment: @Ville-ValtteriTiittanen please see the last function call  if ((wr_uint8(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, ROUTE) == SUCCESS) && (wr_uint8(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, (UINT8)lib_position_reverse()) == SUCCESS) && (wr_uint32(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, route_rev) == SUCCESS) && (wr_crc_ccitt(msg, sizeof(msg), &wr_idx, calc_crc_full(msg, wr_idx) ) == SUCCESS))

Comment: @Chauhan Yes, this answer will work in the latter case you posted.